# How to join using a condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In the country code column there is a difference of GB vs. UK between the two tables. I would like to inner join on route and country

Since in one table it is GB and another UK, the join will skip this row

In the output I would like this row TO BE CONSIDERED and use the value of UK instead of GB for country name

```
SELECT 
    route1,
    country1,
    ship1,
    ship2
FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.route1 = t2.route2
                         AND t1.country1 = t2.country2
```

Table data:

```
    Table1                              Table2
        route1  country1  ship1         route2  country2  ship2
        AE      DE        65            AE      DE        78
        BF      FR        78            BF      FR        43
        ET      UK        43            ET      GB        65
```

Expected OUTPUT

```
 route1 country1    ship1   ship2
    AE       DE      65      78
    BF       FR      78      43
    ET       UK      43      65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case that both values `'GB'` and `'UK'` may exist in the same table, you can use this `CASE` statement in the join:

```
...........................
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.route1 = t2.route2
AND CASE 
  WHEN t1.country1 IN ('UK', 'GB') THEN t2.Country2 IN ('UK', 'GB') 
  ELSE t1.country1 = t2.Country2
END
```

Answer (score 1):

It's awful cumbersome and will probably cause indexes to be ignored (if one exists on these columns being joined) but you could do something like

```
AND CASE WHEN t1.country1 = 'UK' THEN 'GB' ELSE t1.Country1 END = t2.Country2
```

An alternative would be to have a new table sit in between to translate between the two different country codes like:

```
table1_countries | table2_countries
DE               | DE
FR               | FR
UK               | GB
```

Then your FROM clause becomes

```
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN this_new_table ct
  ON t1.country1 = ct.table1_country
INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.route1 = t2.route2
    AND ct.table2_country = t2.country2
```